# Oracle ADF: How to develop a adf web application with a team of 10 members

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hello we need to develop a web application using Oracle ADF and jdeveloper 12c. This is a big project so we need to develop this application with the help of a team of size 10 members. Our doubt is how we can develop a web application using a team.

Suppose that we have 10 modules. Each module has developed by each member(Each member is using different system with same environment. Jdeveloper 12c). Finally developing all the 10 modules how we can combine all the 10 modules as a single application. How we can modify bindings , page flows and connection details.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will suggest posting  this question on ADF Methodology Group Forum which is followed by a large community of ADF experts: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adf-methodology

Comment: This question is probably too open ended and may generate, primarily, opinion based answers to be a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comprehensive look at ADF team size and roles you can find on ADF [Architecture TV channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zo1Z8Cq6z3E).

In terms of architecture, I would suggest [SUM of the Parts Pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ViaSv60e1Q&index=8&list=PLJz3HAsCPVaSemIjFk4lfokNynzp5Euet):

Simply put, every member can use their own workspace where they will create bounded task flows based on fragments. Then, each of those workspaces will be packaged as ADF Libraries and imported into a MASTER workspace, acting as a portal. One of the most common patterns for implementing Master portal is [Dynamic Tabs UI Shell Template Functional UI Pattern](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/uishell-093084.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toEuQvp73h8) to understand ADF large project architecture better, and read [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adfarchitect-1639592.html), [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJz3HAsCPVaRzwcWgFLjMWDDT6OV1x2ma) and [this](http://youtu.be/aMOTcujiBDw)  as well. This [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849681880) may be of use.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach will be using a version control tool like SVN. Initially, anyone member of the team need to migrate the blank project structure to SVN. later on others can checkout the code and implement their code and after that they can check in the code. The problem here is you have to assume that no 2 developers are working on same file at same time, or else code conflict may happen while committing the code.

Currently, I am also working on a project where some developers are from onshore and some from offshore. So, we use  the SVN. Jdevloper itself comes with SVN Client. So no need of installing any SVN client like Tortoise SVN or Smart SVN.

If still you need more information you can reply back.